# An optimization problem defined by optimal transportation

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-transportation

Let $\mu,\nu$ be two probability measures on $E:=\mathbb R^d$ and denote by  $\gamma:=\mu\otimes \nu$ the product measure on $E\times E$. Define $\mathcal K$ to be the class of continuous functions $k:E\times E\to [0,1]$. Provided the continuous and bound cost function $c: E\times E\times [0,1]\to\mathbb R_+$ and the continuous and bounded price function $p: E\times E\to\mathbb R_+$, consider the (entropic) optimal transport problem

$$\inf_{\pi\in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \left\{\Phi_k(\pi):=\int_{E\times E} c\big(x,y,k(x,y)p(x,y)\big)\pi(dx,dy)+\int_{E\times E}\log\left(\frac{d\pi}{d\gamma}(x,y)\right)\gamma(dx,dy)\right\},$$

where $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is the collection of probability measures $\pi$ on $E\times E$ with marginal distributions $\mu,\nu$. As $\pi\mapsto \Phi_k(\pi)$ is strictly convex and continuous (w.r.t. the weak convergence), $\Phi_k$ admits a unique minimiser in $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$, denoted by $\pi_k$, for every $k\in \mathcal K$. Define

$$F(k):=\int_{E\times E} \Big[\big(1-k(x,y)\big)p(x,y)+h\big(x,y,k(x,y)p(x,y)\big)\Big]\pi_k(dx,dy),$$

where $h:E\times E\times E\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and bounded. My question is as follows: Under which conditions $F$ has a minimiser in $\mathcal K$?

1. If $\mu,\nu$ both admit a density function w.r.t. Lebesgue measure;
2. If $c, p , h$ are regular enough?
3. If we enlarge the class $\mathcal K$? E.g. the set of measurable functions taking values in $[0,1]$.

Any answer and comments are highly appreciated.